# How can we count the number of active records using a specific id in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the count of active records by using a specific id , i tried using this code but i did not get proper output.

```
    public function package_category_listing()
{   

    $query = $this->db->get("mn_package_category");
    $data['records'] = $query->result();
    foreach($data['records'] as $r)
    {
    $c=$r->category_id;

    }
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM mn_package WHERE `category_id` = '.$c);
    $data['data']= $query->num_rows();
    $this->load->view('admin/package/package_category_listing',$data );
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea what this line `$c=$r->category_id;` do inside `foreach` loop? it is overwriting `$c` every time.

Comment: yes thai is the category id , with that category id i want to select package from the table

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to find the total records using each 'category_id'?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not much to work with, but just guessing from the code you posted I would rewrite the SQL Statement if possible. Probably something like this:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM mn_package WHERE `category_id` = '.$c. 'AND `active = true`');
```

I don't know what your database looks like, so I guessed that maybe there is a attribute called 'active' or something similar.

Comment: Ups, I meant 'AND `active` = true'